# Why is SQL Server 2008R2 using more memory than the "max server memory" setting?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Memory](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10171/microsoft-sql-server-2008-memory)

I've explicitly set the Maximum Memory value in SQL server 2008R2 to 13,000 MB, however when I check task manager I see it is using 14,071,448 KB (13,741 MB)

I'm concerned because the server crashed recently due to a low memory condition where SQL server had allocated almost all of the server memory.

I've checked and the number I have entered is correct (i.e not entered in KB by mistake).

Answer (score 10):

For SQL Server 2008 R2, "max memory" is for buffer pool only (basically data cache)
Other memory is used for other things.

This is changed in SQL Server 2012

Comment: Ah, well that explains it then.  Thanks for taking the time to answer!

Comment: then how can I set to a particular limit?